# Meteor elemmatch does not match expectations

Tags: mongodb, meteor

in shell / robomongo

```
db.mycol.find({_id:"jodi"},{
            "progress":{
                    $elemMatch:{
                            "status":"todo"
                    }
            }
        });
```

and the
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toZUl.png)
[image]

this my publish

```
Meteor.publish('mycol', function() {
  if(!this.userId)
    return null;
  coli = Coli.find({clientId:this.userId});
  return coli;
});
```

and my helper

```
Coli.find({_id:"jodi"},{
            "progress":{
                    $elemMatch:{
                            "status":"todo"
                    }
            }
        }).fetch()
```

result from console log(meteor)[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpGrU.png)
[image]

i want show only status todo only
not all
if i running on my console(robomongo) its work
but if i running on my script,all data show (not only status todo)

and this my db

```
{
    "_id" : "jodi",
    "clientId" : "BdTw5TtipGkodGLNY",
    "project" : "jodi",
    "progress" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "ewCzYjeid9G5vpqNy",
            "createdAt" : "2016-02-22T12:41:56+07:00",
            "status" : "todo",
            "title" : "jodi",
            "detail" : "jodi"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "ewCzYjeid9G5vpqsNy",
            "createdAt" : "2016-02-22T12:41:56+07:00",
            "status" : "doing",
            "title" : "jodi",
            "detail" : "jodi"
        }
    ]
}
```

i want only show data array in status : todo
in shell it works but in my script status other than todo also appeared

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Coli.find({_id:"jodi"},
          {"progress":{$elemMatch:{"status":"todo"}} },
          {fields:{"progress.$": 1}}
         ).fetch();
```

Comment: same result
status other than todo also appeared
i want show data only status "todo"

Comment: and this my db
{
    "_id" : "jodi",
    "clientId" : "BdTw5TtipGkodGLNY",
    "project" : "jodi",
    "progress" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "ewCzYjeid9G5vpqNy",
            "createdAt" : "2016-02-22T12:41:56+07:00",
            "status" : "todo",
            "title" : "jodi",
            "detail" : "jodi"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "ewCzYjeid9G5vpqsNy",
            "createdAt" : "2016-02-22T12:41:56+07:00",
            "status" : "doing",
            "title" : "jodi",
            "detail" : "jodi"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone
this my fixed code

```
Coli.find({
            "progress":{
                    $elemMatch:{
                            "status":"doing"
                    }
            }
        })
```